# How can I determine which drive to save a text file on?

Tags: vb.net, path, directory-structure

My problem is several (Windows) computers run from different drive letters (C drive, D drive, etc…) and I need to determine the one which the program is running on to save a TXT file of the history and bookmarks and some other stuff that is collected from the web browser that I designed. Visual Basic and C# code would be useful (VB preferred).

Comment: I think you mean *determine where*, not 'define'. `Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [function designed to get you the Windows-defined special folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx), like this (untested):

```
Dim dirBrowserData As String = IO.Path.Combine( _
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), _
        "YourBrowserName")
```

Putting user data on the root of whatever drive you're on is not recommended and may not be possible depending on security settings, but the local (non-roaming) user data should almost always be fine, because that's literally what that Windows API is there for.